# Generate output as array or json agg in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table and I have to generate a specific output in the form of list of array. I have tried with `json_agg`, `array_agg`, `row_to_json`, combination of almost all `agg_functions` and `json_building` functions, but not able to generate the output as needed.

If it is not possible, I can work with simple json structure, also, but before giving up, want to give it a try.

**Table structure**

```sql
create table sample_table
( 
  x_labl character varying,
  x_val1 character varying,
  x_val2 character varying,
  y_labl character varying,
  y_val1 character varying,
  y_val2 character varying
 );
```

Sample_Data

[image: sample_data]

**Want to generate an output like, as below:**

```
"chartData" : [
    ["lablX", 1, 2], ["lablY",  10, 20]
]
```

Comment: Is the `"chartData"` the key of a json object, or the column of the output? What's the output suppose to look like when there are multiple rows in your table?

Comment: "chartData" is the key of the json object.  And there will be only 1 row entry in the table. Thats how I made it, so that it can be doable. Can you help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select array[
    array[x_labl, x_val1, x_val2], 
    array[y_labl, y_val1, y_val2 ]
] as chartData
from sample_table
```

This generates a resultset with just one column called `chartData` and as many rows as there are in the table. Each value is a multi-level array that follows the spec you provided.

If you want a json object instead:

```
select json_build_object(
    'chartData',
    jsonb_build_array(
        jsonb_build_array(x_labl, x_val1, x_val2),
        jsonb_build_array(y_labl, y_val1, y_val2)
    )
) as js
from sample_table
```

Comment: Need to produce a single json object, with key as "chartData". How to I integrate this output. Thats where I am losing. Kindly help.

Comment: yes this will give the list of array as column values and column name as "chartData".  More specifically, I want to have a JSON output where key is "chartData" and values is that array.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is I should have done it. Sometimes, un-learn and learn again helps. Thank you.